# SQLAlchemy TypeDecorator doesn't work

Tags: xml, postgresql, sqlalchemy, elementtree

I'm using `xml` in my postgresql database and I need a custom type could handle `xml` data in SQLAlchemy.

So I made `XMLType` class communicating with `xml.etree`, but It doesn't work as I wished.

here`s the code that I wrote:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

class XMLType(sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator):

    impl = sqlalchemy.types.UnicodeText
    type = etree.Element

    def get_col_spec(self):
        return 'xml'

    def bind_processor(self, dialect):
        def process(value):
            if value is not None:
                return etree.dump(value)
            else:
                return None
        return process

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = etree.fromstring(value)
        return value
```

It works well on retrieving values and result processing. but when I tried to insert a row, I get an error(of course, I put the `body` as `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` object):

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) null value in column "body" violates not-null 
constraint "INSERT INTO comments (id, author_id, look_id, body, created_at) 
VALUES (nextval('object_seq'), %(author_id)s, %(look_id)s, %(body)s, now()) 
RETURNING comments.id" {'body': None, 'author_id': 1550L, 'look_id': 83293L}
```

Seeing that the `body` value is `None`, it's obvious that the binding processor do not work right, but I think I implemented that properly so I don't know what should I do to change the situation.

`process_bind_param` gives me the same error.

Where did I go wrong in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ElementTree.dump()` function dumps XML to stream (stdout by default) and returns `None`. Use `ElementTree.tostring()` or dump it to `StringIO` object.

Comment: Thank you. It was my ignorance, not SQLAlchemy's problem. :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that there's 'accepted answer' feature. I just did it. Thanks for your consideration.